# How can this question have "3 votes, 2 views"?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Just now I saw:

[image: 3 votes, 2 views]

How is it possible that a question has *3 votes, 2 views*?

Comment: It was just 6 votes, 1 answer and 3 views... My guess is that views get updated on a schedule

Comment: Vote early, vote often!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's caching, it's always caching ;)

The view count isn't as important or as likely to change rapidly as the vote count and it's cached more aggressively.